# Does click frequency account for relevance?

Tags: recommender-system, information-retrieval

While building a rank, say for a search engine, or a recommendation system, is it valid to rely on click frequency to determine the relevance of an entry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Depends on the user's intent](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/169639/cikm-clickpatterns.pdf), for starters.

[Users normally only view the first set of links](http://www.seoresearcher.com/distribution-of-clicks-on-googles-serps-and-eye-tracking-analysis.htm), which means that unless the link is viewable, it's not getting clicks; meaning you'd have to be positive those are the best links, otherwise the clicks are most likely going to reflect placement, not relevance. For example, here's a [click and attention distribution heat-map](http://www.seoresearcher.com/distribution-of-clicks-on-googles-serps-and-eye-tracking-analysis.htm) for  Google search results:

[image: Google SEPR Click and Attention distribution ‘heat-map’]

Further, using click frequency to account for relevance is not a direct measure of the resource's relevance. Also, using clicks is problematic, since issues like click-inflation, click-fraud, etc. will pop-up and are hard to counter.

That said, if you're interested in using user interaction to model relevance, I would suggest you attempt to measure post-click engagement, not how users respond to search results; see "[YouTube's head of engineering speaking about clicks vs engagement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCeNCVb-d8)" for more information, though note that the [size itself of the content is a factor](http://www.orbitmedia.com/blog/ideal-blog-post-length/) too.

Might be worth noting that historically Google was known for [PageRank algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) though it's possible your intent is only to review click-streams, so I won't delve [Google ranking factors](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20ranking%20factors); if you are interested in the Google's approach, you might find a review of [Google's Search Quality Rating Guidelines](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/insidesearch/howsearchworks/assets/searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf).

Comment: For the Google search result, top ranks being actually more relevant also influences the click percentage.

Answer (score 7):

For my part I can say that I use click frequency on i.e. eCommerce products. When you combine it with the days of the year it can even bring you great suggestions.

i.e.: We have historical data from 1 year over 2 products (Snowboots[], Sandalettes[])

```
Snowboots[1024,1253,652,123,50,12,8,4,50,148,345,896]
Sandalettes[23,50,73,100,534,701,1053,1503,1125,453,213,25]
```

where [0] = January

As you can see, snowboots are much more searched in January than sandalettes, so you should suggest snowboots to someone searching shoes on your site or /we on january.

You can also see if something is "fresh" at this time, like when people often click a unknown product it could be an insight for a new comming trend or something.

That are just some examples where you could use click frequency as an insight. I think there are **no rules** for what you can use or not in recommendations, **as long as it makes sense**.

Answer (score 5):

Is it valid to *use* click frequency, then **yes**. Is it valid to use **only** the click frequency, then probably **no**.

Search relevance is much more complicated than just one metric. [There are entire books on the subject](http://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=search%20ranking). Extending this answer beyond a simple yes/no would likely make the answer far too broad (and opinionated)